# Turtle methods: hideturtle() and write() in the code below are not working when the program is run

Tags: python, class, object, python-turtle

**Below is the scoreboard.py file, intended to update information about the game level and score for the turtle-crossing game. Upon creating an object for the Scoreboard class, a turtle is created at the centre of the screen. This turtle, however, isn't invisible and does not update the game level.**

```
from turtle import Turtle

FONT = ("Courier", 24, "normal")

class Scoreboard(Turtle):
    def __int__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.hideturtle()
    self.level = 1
    self.penup()
    self.goto(-250, 250)
    self.update_scoreboard()

    def update_scoreboard(self):
        self.clear()
        self.write(f"Level = {self.level}", align="left", font=FONT)

    def update_level(self):
        self.level += 1

    def game_over(self):
        self.goto(0,0)
        self.write(f"GAME OVER", align="center", font=FONT)
```

**Below is the main.py file.**

```
import time
from turtle import Screen
from player import Player
from car_manager import CarManager
from scoreboard import Scoreboard
from turtle import Turtle

player_obj = Player()
car_obj = CarManager()
score_obj=Scoreboard()
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(player_obj.north_key,"Up")

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    screen.update()

    car_obj.car_position()
    car_obj.car_first_move()

    for j in car_obj.car_list:
        if player_obj.distance(j) < 20:
            game_is_on = False
            score_obj.game_over()

    if player_obj.player_outcome():
        player_obj.go_to_start()
        car_obj.car_level_up()
        score_obj.update_level()
        score_obj.update_scoreboard()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: The body for init seems indented improperly.

Comment: Your `Scoreboard` class does absolutely nothing upon instantiation, because it doesn't have an `__init__()` method - you've misspelled it.